# How to find source code of user login in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, sign

As you know, in gitlab, sign in using username and password, without a random verification code. We consider this is not safe enough and try to add verification code in Sign in page.

When user clicking Sign in, the browser send a HTTTP POST request to http://mydomain/users/sign_in url, my question is:where is the source code receive this request and do the sign in. I think this is where to add verification code logic.

I am using gitlab 7.6.1, and new to ruby and rails. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the GitLab team is accepting pull request regarding [2FA (Two Factor authentication)](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4516817-implement-two-factor-authentication-2fa) and [2FA with Yubikey](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6316364-two-factor-authentication-with-yubikey).

In the meantime, you can [search the code for 'sign_in'](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sign_in&type=Code), which includes [`app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/8188427e83f55df1f9750786c2a457976d4ebca7/app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb#L9) and various other controllers, all calling [`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/fdfa79a79e24e84f9fcb4a0a605a5bb00d9146c4/app/controllers/application_controller.rb): that is where authetication controls are done.

Comment: hi @VonC, can you tell which method in app/controllers/application_controller.rb handler signin?  thanks.

Comment: @Feng Not sure actually, I don't see a `def sign_in` anywhere (maybe it is managed by a third-part library?)